# Broadcasting by GSM Antenna

Tags: android, arduino, gsm, cellular-network

My question is about sending or receiving data directly on gsm antennas.(P2P)

According to its documentation, arduino gsm shield lets me send/receive text message or make call to a specific number.

I want to make data broadcasting using gsm antenna.So I need to write a new driver to gsm shield, or not?

And is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing [GSM library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSM) from arduino site. This library helps to execute common requests to SIM card include sending of SMS messages.

> This library enables an Arduino board to do most of the operations you can do with a GSM phone: place and receive voice calls, send and receive SMS, and connect to the internet over a GPRS network.

Take look at [this sample](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesSendSMS). I suppose, it's what you are looking for